# Local DNS configuration and best practices

Tags: dns

I have recently set up a PowerDNS + PowerAdmin server on my home network. I have set this up as a combination authoritative + recursive DNS server just to keep things simple for me. I have set 8.8.8.8 as the recursor.

I have confirmed that I can do: "dig google.com @(ip of dns server)" and it works great.

My goal basically is to be able to use DNS on my home network for the various vms that I'm running. Let's use wiki servers for this example.

I was originally going to be doing something like: wiki01.catpants.lan for the names, but I was told this is a bad idea. (using a fake tld) So now I'll just buy a domain and do things like wiki.catpants.com (or whatever I decide to use).

So I have a few questions.

1. Is it considered ok to use 8.8.8.8 for the recursor? I know google's DNS servers are commonly used, but I was wondering if maybe there is a more appropriate choice.
2. I want to be able to tell at a glance if a server is "internal only" or is available externally also. I was considering using another subdomain, so it would be something like wiki01.lan.catpants.com for an "internal only" wiki, and wiki02.catpants.com for an externally available wiki. It would work, but I think is a bit ugly and requires extra typing. Or, should I buy and use a domain name just for internal use? Seems like a bit of a waste to me, since I have external services I want to run anyway. See, using .lan definitely has some advantages in my mind. The advantages being free and easy to tell if a server is internal only or available externally.
3. (Main question) I've been trying to test creating a few internal dns records with a domain I already own. Call it foo.com. I am using he.net for the nameservers for foo.com currently. When I try to create a master zone for foo.com with poweradmin, it creates an SOA record for it, but the defaults are: `8.8.8.8  2016081300 28800 7200 604800 86400`
   IIRC, When configuring poweradmin for the first time, it asked me a question about some sort of defaults (possibly SOA related). Not knowing what goes there, I just put 8.8.8.8 thinking it was asking about the recursor. Of course it looks like there is no way to edit that setting now, so not sure what it was. **What should the SOA record look like?**
4. Should I be using DNSSEC? I can research it on my own if it's considered "best practice".
5. Is it possible to get "leakage"? ie, I think from a security perspective it would be nice if packets with my internal DNS records never get routed on the internet. If someone was capturing all outbound traffic from my network, the string "wiki01.lan.catpants.com" should *never* appear in that traffic. Could that occur with this setup?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please configure separate DNS services for internal and external clients. This can be done with split DNS or different servers. I use both options.

1. If you are doing recursive queries you should start with the root servers.  They should be populated from the hints file.  Don't provide this service to hosts connecting from the internet.  If you do you will find your network bandwidth is used to create amplification attacks.
2. There are several mechanisms for separating external and internal entries.  Using a subdomain is one.  Configure these addresses so that they don't leak to the internet.  Buying a separate domain for internal use is overkill.
3. Your internal address should not be listed on the he.net domain servers.  The addresses should not be valid on the internet and should not be served by an internet-facing DNS server.  Create your own internal zone for these addresses.
4. At some point you should use DNSSEC. Leave this until later.
5. Use a private IP address from the range 10.0.0./8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16, and traffic won't be routed to the internet. In any case, if your DNS server and clients are on the same LAN, traffic won't be routed between servers over the internet.